# How to remove 'all duplicated ' values?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector, stl

There`s a lot of tutorials exist for removing duplicate values and I have checked all

like

{1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5} -> {1,2,3,4,5}

by using sort(), unique() function.

but if I want to remove 'all duplicated' values

like

{1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5} -> {5}

How to implement it?

I have manually split the original vector into two parts and remove the duplicated elements in first one by later one.

It makes sense but if the original vector size became huge, then I cannot split the original vector manually.

Comment: "but if I want to remove 'all duplicated' values" - So you want to only save values which appear exactly once?

Comment: Maybe iterate over each element and check if the first element is found at another index then store both index  in variables then erase

Comment: @OP -- You had specified this in your question: *It makes sense but if the original vector size became huge,* -- but you accepted an answer that is less than optimal, while the other solutions offer much better time complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution using range-v3:

```cpp
namespace rv = ranges::views;
    
ranges::sort(v);
   
auto res = v 
      | rv::group_by(std::equal_to{}) 
      | rv::filter([](auto r) { return ranges::size(r) == 1; }) 
      | rv::join
      | ranges::to<std::vector<int>>;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/As4RL4).

Here's an `O(n log(n))` in-place solution, using the STL:

```cpp
auto begin = v.begin(), end = v.end();
    
std::sort(begin, end);

while(begin != end)
  if (auto f = std::find_if(begin + 1, end, 
                 [begin](int i) { return i != *begin; });
      begin + 1 != f)  // if duplicate elements found
    end = std::move(f, end, begin);   // move them to the end
  else ++begin;
  
v.erase(end, v.end());
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/_tmz8s).

Comment: Nice, but I have a question: can it be done inplace (in vector v) using ranges?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl It's possible, but nothing comes to mind.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Added an in-place solution as well.

Comment: thank you, cant upvote since I already upvoted before :)

Comment: In-place solution using ranges: `v = ranges::actions::sort(v) | ranges::views::chunk_by(std::equal_to{}) | ranges::views::filter([](auto r) { return ranges::size(r) == 1; }) | ranges::views::join | ranges::to<std::vector<int>>;`

Answer (score 3):

My advice: Don't try to do it in-place.

I would sort the vector, and then make a pass through, identifying elements that occur more than once (which should be easy, since they're now adjacent), and writing those that do not into another vector.

An interface similar to `copy_if`

`OutIter copy_unique(Iterator first, Iterator last, OutIter out);`

That is an `O(n log n + n)` solution.

An in-place solution (like @william_ suggests) would be `O(N^2)`

Comment: `O(n log n + n) = O(n log n)`, and it is possible to do it in-place in `O(n log n)` by first sorting and then removing elements which occur more than once in a similar manner to `std::remove`.

Comment: Sure it's possible to do it in place; but it's easier if you can make a copy of the non-duplicated elements. Hence my "advice"

Answer (score 2):

An `unordered_map` should deal with the case:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5};
    int n = 9;
    unordered_map<int, int> counter;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        counter[arr[i]]++;
    }
    
    vector<int> ans;
    
    for (auto& it: counter) {
        if(it.second == 1) ans.push_back(it.first);
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < ans.size(); i++) cout<<ans[i]<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

It simply counts the occurrences of the elements of the array. If the occurrence count of an element is 1, it is unique, so you store it in a vector or array (of the size of the map).

Complexity: O(n) time and space.

You can also use `unordered_multiset`, since it stores the element count as well.

Comment: Those first two lines make for a bad answer.

Comment: `<bits/stdc++.h>` is not part of standard C++.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry that I basically repeat the answer of user Daniel, but because I saw the first 2 lines of his code, I have to. I am sorry.

So, what you actually want, and that should be the question, is: How can I get the values in an array that occur exactly once?

And that question leads you already to the answer. You need to count the occurences of each value in an array. And that can easily be done using a `std::map` or a `std::unordered map`.

It has a index operator [] which does the following:

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.

Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) for details.

So, in any way, it will return a refence to a value in the `std::map`. And with the post increment operator we will do the count.

Then we can simply show the result on the screen, resulting in a really very compact program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    // The test data
    std::vector values{ 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5 };

    // We will count all instances of values
    std::map<int, size_t> counter{};
    for (const int i : values) counter[i]++;

    // Display the result
    for (const auto& [value, count] : counter) 
        if (1==count) std::cout << value << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to have the result in a different `std::vector`, then you can simply use a small for loop and `push_back` the values with a count of 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> list = { 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5 };
    vector<int> rest;
    

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
            if (list[i] == list[j]) {
                count++;
                
            }
        }
        if (count == 1) {
            rest.push_back(list[i]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rest.size(); i++) {
        cout << rest[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

simply you just need to use 2 for loops for the implementation.

Comment: Now imagine if there were 10000 elements -- You would loop 100000000 times.  The OP specified that the array can become large.

Comment: we have to use a map,